# Jsonnet - variable turned into literal string

Tags: jsonnet

I'm having trouble with this snippet where I want to pass in value using a variable but it becomes a literal string.

```
test: if variableA then {
  'hello': '{"foo": bar}'
},
```

I want to be to be variable and I expect `bar` to be the value I've passed in as a parameter but it is literally the word `bar`

Comment: Could you please explain more clearly the executed command and the output you expect exactly?

Comment: Looks like the whole `'{"foo": bar}'` is inside a string? Did you mean `{"foo": bar}` instead?

Answer (score 2):

The question is lacking a little context, such as how `bar` was assigned, and perhaps why you are trying to write an object as a string literal.

Assuming there is a value assigned to `bar` somewhere, on way to write this would be to use string interpolation:

```
test: if variableA then {
  hello: '{"foo": %s}' % bar
}
```

Also, key names only need to be quoted if they contain unsupported characters.